# Inserting record into database using JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Following is my code

```
<?php
$json = '{"apples":"green","bananas":"yellow"}';
$var=(json_decode($json, true));
print_r($var);

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the eventbase
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//select a eventbase to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("json",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select json");

// Insert $event array into eventbase
    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $db_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fruits (fruit,color) VALUES" . $value);
    mysql_query($db_insert);
    if (!$db_insert)
    {
    die('Could not connect - event insert failed: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    }
?>
```

New to JSON and PHP, please post any changes I can do to insert those records into MySQL.

However, another part remains. I want to save the JSON encoded data into MySQL in string format. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$var` as below,

```
foreach ($var as $fruit => $color) {
    $db_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fruits (fruit,color) VALUES ('$fruit','$color')");
    .....
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: do you mean `$var as $fruit => $color`?

Comment: Error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_query' (T_STRING) in simple.php on line 22

Comment: there is nothing more to it except a db which consists of 2 fields , fruit and color .

Comment: It is passing empty fields into db , n dis is coming right now  - Notice: Undefined variable: fruit in /opt/lampp/htdocs/example/simple1.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: color in /opt/lampp/htdocs/example/simple1.php on line 21

Comment: Are you sure you change foreach as I mention ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47002/discussion-between-rikesh-and-caffeine-coder)

Comment: how can i save the json encoded data back again into db ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I will suggest you to ask a different question for that.

Comment: did it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629922/inserting-json-encoded-data-into-mysql as you requested

Answer (score 0):

I think you havn't used the correct variable in the for loop. After json decode you used the same variable in the for loop. (you should use $var instead of $json) i guess.

```
<?php
$json = '{"apples":"green","bananas":"yellow"}';
$var=(json_decode($json, true));
//print_r($var);

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the eventbase
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//select a eventbase to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("json",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select json");

// Insert $event array into eventbase
    foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
    $db_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fruits (fruit,color) VALUES" . $value);
    mysql_query($db_insert);
    if (!$db_insert)
    {
    die('Could not connect - event insert failed: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Error - Could not connect - event insert failed: Query was empty