# Inserting json encoded data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is a follow up question , earlier i had [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622946/inserting-record-into-database-using-json)
 about inserting json into mysql . I encoded it again and now i want it to be printed back to mysql . I don't know how am i supposed to print the encoded json output as string back into mysql . Folowing is my current code

```
<?php
$json = array
   (
   array("pineapple","yellow"),
   array("watermelon","red"),
   array("orange","orange")
   );
var_dump($json);
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

$newelements = json_encode( $json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
echo $newelements;

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 


$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


$selected = mysql_select_db("json",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select json");


  //  foreach ($enc as $fruit => $color) {

    $db_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fruits (fruit,color) VALUES('$fruit','$color')");
    mysql_query($db_insert);


    if (!$db_insert)
    {
    die('Could not connect - event insert failed: ' . mysql_error());
    }
  //  }
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated .Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As I understand you want to add JSON text to the database? That is just a string so you can add it to a (var)char column.

Comment: do i need to define an extra column in db for that ? Can u show me exactly how that's gonna happen , bit of a newbie to json .

Comment: Careful with SQL injections! One can put whatever one wants in $fruit or $color here.

Comment: I know , but this is just for my learning purpose . I will start using PDO in near future , but i need to know how am i gonna achieve doing this first .

Comment: JSON means JavaScript Object Notation. If you `json_encode` the array, it will create a `string` with the array in a JSON format. The string can be easily stored in the database in a (new) column with the datatype `char` or `varchar`.

Comment: can u reflect what changes should i do in my code ? Worked on it the whole day so out of ideas how am i gonna do it :(

Answer (score -1):

Because you have an array of arrays, the correct `foreach` would look like this:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($newelement as $element) {
    $values[] = "('".mysql_real_escape_string($element[0])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($element[1])."')";
}

$db_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fruits (fruit,color) VALUES ".implode(",", $values);
```

Comment: foreach() for running a query?? You know a single query can have multiple rows inserted at once. No need to loop like you are as it is very inefficient.

Comment: You are perfectly right, I fixed the code reflecting this :)

Comment: no need for the array usage, just use string concatenation.